# Parameter without type specifier

Tags: c

It's possible in C do handle variable variables like in PHP. Here is my a example from the PHP documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

I would like do something like this, to get some abstraction of my code.

```
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;

function handle_value(variable_var) {
     scanf("%i", &variable_var);
}
```

This is how it work's, but I want to get less code ...

```
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;
scanf("%i", &value1);
scanf("%i", &value2);
scanf("%i", &value3);
```

Comment: Have you read about `scanf` at all before asking?

Comment: Just use an array? I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but if it's about dynamic variables, rarely is their use justified. Use arrays for variables that vary by a number, or a Map for variables that differ in some other way.

Comment: Array and loop: `int val[3]; for (int j=0; j<3; j++) scanf("%d", val+j);`

Comment: I think the question here is about variadic functions.

Comment: Is it just changing the value of a variable inside a function? And "**It's** possible in C do handle variable variables like in PHP. Here is my a example from the PHP documentation." makes me feel a statement

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. As can be reeaad by every good C book and Wikipedia, C ist statically typed, if that's what you mean. And that has nothing to do with abstraction.

Comment: Strictly speaking, C doesn't support the "variable variable" feature.

Comment: I edited the title. Something like "beginner" or the language don't belong into the title. f it does not match what you mean, please clarify. Also take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: @Olaf I think, you changed the title wrong. He needs somethink like pointers and he is not interested in types.

Comment: @j123b567: `function handle_value(variable_var)` tells different. Looks like OP wants a dynamically typed variable. But as asked, the question is indeed unclear. I voted to close. To me it looks like OP needs to learn C basics to know what he wants. Until then feel free to edit the title as you think.

Comment: @ToyRobotic can you write equivalent code in PHP so we can see what you really mean?

Comment: What OP wants is, I believe, something like `char a[] = "b"; int b = 42; printf("%d\n", somemagicwith(a)) /* 42 */; strcpy(a, "c"); int c = -1; printf("%d\n", somemagicwith(a)) /* -1 */;`.

Comment: @pmg thats what I mean, so the nearest c eqvivalent, that works is `int b = 42; int * a = &b; printf("%d\n", somemagicwith(a)) /* 42 */; int c = -1; a = &c; printf("%d\n", somemagicwith(a)) /* -1 */;`

Comment: And `somemagicwith(a)` can be written as `*a`. That works, but it's not really equivalent.

Comment: You need to check the return value from each of the `scanf()` operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C does not handle variable variables like in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to achieve what you mentioned.

Just do this:

```
#define LIST_OF_VARIABLES X(value1) X(value2) X(value3)


//Declaring the variables

#define X(name) int name;
LIST_OF_VARIABLES
#undef X



//Reading values into the variables

#define X(name) scanf("%i", &name);
LIST_OF_VARIABLES
#undef X



//Printing the values

#define X(name) printf("\n%i", name);
LIST_OF_VARIABLES
#undef X
```

First we define a macro `LIST_OF_VARIABLES` which will be calling another macro `X`.
We keep `LIST_OF_VARIABLES` the way it is as it will be used over and over again.

Next we define the macro `X` which was used in the body of `LIST_OF_VARIABLES`.
This second macro is the one that we modify to fit our needs.

Each time we change the purpose of the second macro `X`, we first undefine it with `#undef` and then redefine it `#define`.

The above code will be end up first as follows after expanding `LIST_OF_VARIABLES` macro:

```
//Declaring the variables

#define X(name) int name;
X(value1) X(value2) X(value3)
#undef X



//Reading values into the variables

#define X(name) scanf("%i", &name);
X(value1) X(value2) X(value3)
#undef X



//Printing the values

#define X(name) printf("\n%i", name);
X(value1) X(value2) X(value3)
#undef X
```

Then after expanding the `X()` macro each time, the [C pre-processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) would finally give the following (which will then be used by the compiler):

```
//Declaring the variables

int value1; int value2; int value3;   



//Reading values into the variables

scanf("%i", &value1); scanf("%i", &value2); scanf("%i", &value3);



//Printing the values

printf("\n%i", value1); printf("\n%i", value2); printf("\n%i", value3);
```

which is the output you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Variable variables are similar to pointers in your example. So you can do something like this.

```
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;

void handle_value(int * var) {
    scanf("%i", var);
}

int main(void) {
    handle_value(&value1);
    handle_value(&value2);
    handle_value(&value3);
}
```